# Assign a string to InnerHtml of a HtmlElement obeject

Tags: c#, html, html-parsing

I try to fill up a "Select" element in my HTML while it's open on my own browser in a C# application. So i did this:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
HtmlElement States = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Select1");
da.Fill(dt);
States.InnerHtml = "";
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    string head = String.Format(@"<option Value=""{1}"">", 
        dt.Rows[i]["Code"].ToString());
     string body = String.Format("{0}</option>", dt.Rows[i]["Name"].ToString());
     string tag = head + body;

     States.InnerHtml =tag;
}
```

But surprisingly when I expect to result be something like this

```
< option Value="aNumber">testString<\option>
```

I see this:

```
testString<\option>
```

I saw the same problem here when I was struggling to write the expected string. Finally I inserted a blank space to the second char on my string.  Thus I worte `< option>` instead of `<option>` in here.  I did same for that string which I want to pass to the `InnerHtml` property of my element.  But unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: What is the element type of the element with ID `Select1`?

Comment: Why is this `@"<option Value=""{1}"">"` have {1} instead of {0} ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't this

```
string head = String.Format(@"<option Value=""{1}"">", 
        dt.Rows[i]["Code"].ToString());
```

be this?

```
string head = String.Format(@"<option Value=""{0}"">", 
        dt.Rows[i]["Code"].ToString());
```